# NHibernate error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Unrecognized configuration section session-factory

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to connect my aplication to a sql server 2012 database, but its not working and its giving the error that appears on the title, someone could help me? here is the code:

```
`

<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <!-- an ISessionFactory instance -->
      <session-factory>
        <!-- properties -->
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
          User ID=****;Password=****;Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="NHibernate.Auction.Item.hbm.xml" assembly="NHibernate.Auction"/>
        <mapping resource="NHibernate.Auction.Bid.hbm.xml" assembly="NHibernate.Auction"/>
      </session-factory>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

`

Comment: If this is a new application, use nhibernate mapping by code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc for more configuration examples

#### [Chapter 23. Example: Weblog Application](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-weblog-code)

here is a snippet of such setting *(check the **`<configSections>`**)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <!-- Add this element -->
  <configSections>
    <section
        name="hibernate-configuration"
        type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- Add this element -->
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
```